# How to answer Calculus by Michael Spivak Chapter 5 Problem 15.VII

Tags: calculus

I need to evaluate :

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x \sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}$$

In terms of the number:

$$\alpha = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$

What I am thinking is that $\cos(x) = 1 - 2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})$

But I don't know how to proceed.

I know an easy way is to use L'Hopital (the answer would be 2) but the objective is not to use derivates.

Comment: Your idea is fine. Write what you have as $\frac{\sin x}x \frac{x^2}{2 {\sin}^2(x/2) }$ and take it from there.

Comment: Hint: Using power series for $ \cos$ and $ \sin $ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{ x \left( x- \frac{x^3}{3!}+ \cdots \right)}{ 1- \left( 1- \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4!} +\cdots \right)}= ?
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{x \sin x}{1-\cos x} = \frac{x \sin x}{2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})} = \frac{4(\frac{x}{2})^2}{2x}\frac{\sin x}{\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})} = 2\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\left(\frac{\frac{x}{2}}{\sin (\frac{x}{2})}\right)^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

Make the trig substitution you mentioned, then split up the fraction to make fractions in the form of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ or $\frac{x}{\sin(x)}$.  Also, note that the $x$ in these form can be $x/2$ as well.  You will need to bring in some extra $x$'s to make these forms.

Answer (score 0):

Use

$$\sin{x}=2\sin{x\over 2}\cos{x\over 2}$$
$$1-\cos{x}=2\sin^2{x\over 2}$$

To get

$${x\sin{x}\over 1-\cos{x}}=2{{x\over 2}\cos{x\over 2}\over \sin{x\over 2}}\to {2\over\alpha}$$

because when $x\to 0$, $\cos{x\over 2}\to 1$ and ${x/2\over \sin{x/2}}\to 1/\alpha$

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}  \frac{xsin(x)}{1-cos(x)}$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}  \frac{xsin(x)}{1-cos(x)}* \frac{1+cos(x)}{1+cos(x)}$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}  \frac{xsin(x)}{sin^2(x)}* (1+cos(x))$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}  \frac{x}{sin(x)}* (1+cos(x))$

$1\times 2 = 2$